# Spark 2.0.1:scala: temporary view query fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark, view, temporary

I run spark 2.0.1 and ran into issues at the time of querying only:

1. create rows of rdd from original rdd
2. create schema from rdd
3. create dataframe

I tested again:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

val peopleDF = sparkSession.sparkContext
  .textFile("/home/raja/scala_code/text2.dat")
  .map(_.split("|"))
  .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()

peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

val teenagersDF = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM people")

teenagersDF.show()
```

When I fired `sparkSession.sql("SELECT name FROM emp")`, it gives below error.

```
    { java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true) AS name#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true) AS age#1
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 1
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true) AS salary#2
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 2
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true) AS birthplace#3
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row 
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true) AS age#1
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 1
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true) AS salary#2
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 2
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true) AS birthplace#3
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 3
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_1$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:276)
    ... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1935)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1934)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:486)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)
  ... 64 elided
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true) AS name#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true) AS age#1
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 1
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true) AS salary#2
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 2
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 2, salary)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true) AS birthplace#3
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 3
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 3, birthplace)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:279)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_1$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:276)
  ... 20 more}
```

Comment: please post the code that creates `emp` - Spark evaluates views _lazily_ so the fact that the exception is thrown only when querying does not mean that the error is in the query, it might be coming from the code creating the view.

Comment: I am adding two parts one here and another below val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("example").getOrCreate()

    val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
    import sparkSession.implicits._

//val emprdd = sc.textFile("/home/raja/scala_code/text2.dat").map(_.split("|")).map(p => Row(p(0),p(1))) val schemaString = "name birthplace"
val fields = schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)

Comment: val semprdd=emprdd.map(value => Row(value))

val empDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(semprdd, schema)
empDF.createOrReplaceTempView("emp")

val results = sparkSession.sql("SELECT name FROM emp") results.show()

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40624477/edit) your question with this information, code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: I tested again: 

case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
val peopleDF = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("/home/raja/scala_code/text2.dat").map(_.split("|")).map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()

peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

val teenagersDF = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM people")

teenagersDF.show()

gives the error as pasted "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string"

Answer (score 1):

First, `split("|")` doesn't split by pipe as you expect, because `split(s: String)` expects a *regular expression* as input, and pipe is a special character in regular expressions. See more details and solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40359414/5344058

If issue persists after fixing that (your question doesn't provide sample input data so I can't be sure), the exception (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`) is pretty indicative - your code assumes that the result of `split("|")` on each record produces an array with at least **two** items:

```
.map(_.split("|"))
.map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt))
//                                                  ^
//                                                  |
// this will throw exception if input isn't valid --/
```

If any record fails to comply with this condition, you'll see this exception.

To avoid this - there are a few routes you can take. If you just want to **skip** invalid rows, you can use `collect` instead of `map` with a Partial Function that is defined only for Arrays with at least two items:

```
.map(_.split("\\|"))
.collect { case Array(a1, a2, _*) => Person(a1, a2.trim.toInt) }
```

This code will just filter out all records for which the `split` produces an array with less then two records.

Comment: Well, the code I suggested works for simple pipe-separated data (I used `RAJA|123|Pynursla`), so unless you provide some sample data for which it fails (by editing the question again) I can't help any further.

Comment: Yep, I changed the class definition with proper type and mapping too should be exactly typed and it works. It seems that type conversion is taking a lot of doing :)